# inline click and event handler issue

Tags: javascript

I use this code for modal windows with html content - printing

I am having issues with click and responding to events, I have had no response when i click, and sometimes i have to click frequently and refreshing oage then i might get respond.

```
<span class="print_m" id="closeme"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

```
jQuery("#closeme").click(function () {
        var contents = jQuery("#printContent").html();
        var frame1 = jQuery('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        jQuery("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>document class2</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('<link href="../wp-content/themes/MCC/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 50);
    });
```